# Selection of selectManyCheckbox component programmatically

Tags: java, oracle-adf

How can I set selection of an `af:selectManyCheckbox` item programmatically?

I have an old ADF version and I try to create an item in this list, which selects all remaining items if I click it:

```
<af:selectManyCheckbox value="#{usersByRoleFBB.selectedRolesId}"
                       valueChangeListener="#{usersByRoleFBB.listChanged}"
                       required="true" showRequired="true" label="Роли: ">
  <f:selectItems value="#{usersByRoleFBB.listRoleItems}" />
</af:selectManyCheckbox>
```

My java class:

```
private List<SelectItem> listRoleItems;
private Long[] selectedRolesId;

public void listChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Long oldValue = (Long) event.getOldValue();
    Long newValue = (Long) event.getNewValue();
    if (oldValue == -1 || newValue == -1) {
        if (newValue == -1L) {
            for (SelectItem selectItem : listRoleItems) {
                selectItem.setValue(true);
            }
        } 
        if (oldValue == -1L) {
            for (SelectItem selectItem : listRoleItems) {
                selectItem.setValue(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ADF 11g you can programatically change the selection by changing the content of selectedRolesId list. I think the same should work in older versions too.